# Having trouble submitting a login form with Python-Requests (200 Reponse but Expecting 302)

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to log-in to a website using Python requests. My setup is:

```
headers = {
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'origin': 'https://www.naturalpartners.com',
'referer':'https://www.naturalpartners.com/us/account/login.jsp',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {'_dyncharset': 'UTF-8',
'_dynSessConf': '',
'/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.flowName': 'B2B',
'_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.flowName': ' ',
'/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.loginSuccessURL': '/us/index.jsp?',
'_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.loginSuccessURL': ' ',
'/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.loginErrorURL': '/us/account/login.jsp?',
'_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.loginErrorURL': ' ',
'/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.login': '__UsernameHidden__',
'_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.login': ' ',
'/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.password': '__PasswordHidden__',
'_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.password': ' ',
'/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.login': 'Sign In',
'_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.login': ' ',
'_DARGS': '/us/account/login.jsp'}
```

My code to execute the login is:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession() #new session
url = 'https://www.naturalpartners.com/us/account/login.jsp?_DARGS=/us/account/login.jsp'
r = session.get('https://www.naturalpartners.com/us/account/login.jsp', headers = headers) #get login page
dyn = r.html.xpath('//input[@name="_dynSessConf"]/@value')[0] #store _dynSessConf
payload['_dynSessConf'] = dyn #assign to payload
headers['cookie'] = r.headers['Set-Cookie'] #attempt to set cookie value
post = session.post(url, data = payload, headers=headers)
```

My issue is I'm getting a 200 response as opposed to a 302 which would signal a successful login. The post seems to be completing the form with the username and password but not actually submitting it. So the login doesn't actually take place. I'm not sure what step I'm missing. Thank you

Comment: For one thing, it's spelled `referer`, not `referrer`.

Comment: I appreciate that catch. I updated that and unfortunately it did not solve the issue. Still a good note because I always seem to spell that wrong. Will fix now.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the returned page source after the 200, to see if it contains any helpful error messages?

Comment: I have but unfortunately I've seen no errors. All I see is that my payload username and password values are inserted as values in the input fields of the login form but the redirect to the home page that typically takes place with manual login never happens